# What's the difference between state legislator and congress member?

Tags: constitution, government, form-of-government, state-legislatures

I was [reading this article](https://www.americanthinker.com/articles/2020/11/the_direction_of_america_is_in_the_hands_of_state_legislators_.html).
As a non-US citizen, I wonder what does **State Legislators** mean.

I know that US political system is bicameral: senate and congress.
This extends from the federal level to the state level.

So my question is whether the term 'state-legislator' equivalent to congress member at *state* level?

Comment: It might be helpful to think of USA like EU and the states as European nations, if the EU were much older and stronger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. A State Legislator is the state equivalent of a Federal Legislator such as Representative or Senator. Most states model their legislature like the federal Congress, while Nebraska and Washington D.C. do not.

Comment: Thanks. Lastly is 'state legislators' the same person that plays the role as "elector" of the Electoral College?

Comment: @neversaint no the are different individuals. And different numbers of individuals. Alaska has 3 EC votes but 60 members of its state congress. 8n another example Hiliary Clinton is a New York Elector, but not a member of any legislature. https://www.cnn.com/2020/10/28/politics/hillary-clinton-electoral-college-elector/index.html This should really have been a new question though.

Comment: @neversaint not often. The state legislators appoint the electors of the electoral college technically, but the potential electors are chosen depending on the state rules. In California, the individual parties for president have their own rules. Democrats chose from potential US congress nominees, while the Republicans all the Californian state senators and governors and others to be electors. So the parties chose their electors and the state legislators approve that list if that party wins the election.

Comment: Based on https://www.nass.org/sites/default/files/surveys/2017-08/research-state-laws-pres-electors-nov16.pdf there is no state that prevents state legislators from being electors by state rule.